# yum + yum dependencies

Tags: linux, yum, dependencies

I want to install the barman pkg - (this backup server)
during yum , yum failed on dependencies

I not understand well what yum is really neded from the errors down
my python version on my linux is 2.7.5
I not sure according to yum error , but seems that yum need the old python version - 2.7  - so need to perform python downgrade ?

please advice what is needed to resolve this dependencies and what I need to do in this case?

yum     install barman
.
.

```
       Error: Package: python-argh-0.23.2-1.el6.noarch (epel)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
       Installed: python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.2)
           python(abi) = 2.7
           python(abi) = 2.7
       Available: python34-3.4.5-2.el6.i686 (epel)
           python(abi) = 3.4
       Error: Package: python-argcomplete-0.8.8-1.el6.noarch (epel)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
       Installed: python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.2)
           python(abi) = 2.7
           python(abi) = 2.7
       Available: python34-3.4.5-2.el6.i686 (epel)
           python(abi) = 3.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are running CentOS/Redhat 7.  The errors seem to be occurring due to the inclusion of the Epel repository for CentOS/Redhat version 6.

**EDIT:**

According to [this wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), download and install [epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm).

```
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

You can verify these packages and their keys from the Fedora project's keys page: https://fedoraproject.org/keys.

Be sure to remove (or at a minimum, disable) the `epel el6` repository.

Comment: so in this case how to download epel for version 7 ( redhat )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly there is confusion about dependencies of the barman package.

You can find out the dependencies of a package that is not yet installed by using the repoquery tool.

```
repoquery --requires <package>
```

Since you might already have some of the dependencies satisfied, list only the ones that remain outstanding using:

```
repoquery --requires --resolve <package>
```

If you run into a similar situation on an Ubuntu based system, the apt tool can provide the same information via:

```
apt depends <package>
```